# How do you git fetch then merge? "Error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch

Newbie Git question: I have a repo set up on bitbucket. I git fetched someone else's changes and would like to merge them with my own. However, when I try to git merge (or git merge origin/master), I get the message "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:", and then a list of files I've changed. Having Git merge these changes is exactly what I want to do though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore error on git pull about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-to-ignore-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-m)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can either commit your changes before you do the merge, or you stash them:

```
git stash
git merge origin/master
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep your changes, you can commit your changes to your local repository first and then merge the remote repository.

Comment: You can only merge on the remote repository, not locally?

Comment: @ario, you will be able to merge (locally), **after** your local changes will be committed. Or else you will lose those changes.