# How do I ignore an error on 'git pull' about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

How do I ignore the following error message on Git pull?

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

What if I **want** to overwrite them?

I've tried things like `git pull -f`, but nothing works.

To be clear, I only want to overwrite specific changes, not everything.

Comment: Related but no duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch totally agree!  Plus, it's not much of a 'merge' if it's 'overwriting' is it?  I miss SVN every day...

Comment: `git config core.fileMode false` save my times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Comment: What if I don't want to overwrite them?

Answer (score 431, accepted):

Alright with the help of the other two answers I've come up with a direct solution:

```
git checkout HEAD^ file/to/overwrite
git pull
```

Comment: This worked for me. Could you expand on this answer, ie. what is this actually doing?

Comment: It's dropping local changes, reverting to the HEAD reference which is probably the last commit in the master branch

Comment: why HEAD^ instead of HEAD?

Comment: HEAD^ is short for HEAD^1, which essentially means the one commit before HEAD. You could also do HEAD^2 for the commit before that one. For more information see http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955985/what-does-the-caret-character-mean.

Comment: please explain what this does in the answer

Comment: This solution was only one working for me when i had a file with --assume-unchanged that was never shown in the changes to be commited so i could not stash it. Really good solution!.

Comment: After doing this, it said "You are in 'detached HEAD' state." and I found myself in state where `git pull` now says "You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with.".  I gave up and restored from backup where I did not have the unwanted changes. :(  It really should not be this difficult.

Comment: In my case it, didn't work. But:  git checkout HEAD -- my-file.txt worked for me.

Answer (score 654):

If you want remove all local changes - including files that are untracked by git - from your working copy, simply stash them:

```
git stash push --include-untracked
```

If you don't need them anymore, you now can drop that stash:

```
git stash drop
```

If you don't want to stash changes that you already staged - e.g. with `git add` - then add the option `--keep-index`. Note however, that this will still prevent merging if those staged changes collide with the ones from upstream.

---

If you want to overwrite only specific parts of your local changes, there are two possibilities:

1. Commit everything you don't want to overwrite and use the method above for the rest.
2. Use `git checkout path/to/file/to/revert` for the changes you wish to overwrite. Make sure that file is not staged via `git reset HEAD path/to/file/to/revert`.

Comment: Possibility #2 does not work. After executing the command nothing happens. On pull I still get the same error.

Comment: @user1132363: It works for me. Please test it first with a single file. Also, you have make sure that the file you want to overwrite is not staged.

Comment: The trick was to use `git checkout HEAD^ path/to/file/to/revert`. Using **HEAD^** made all the difference.

Comment: @user1132363: That checks out the previous version and not the one currently checked in. I don't believe that this is the correct approach.

Comment: What if I am not able to do a stash because I have no changed files in my working copy? I get the error message despite having no local changes.

Comment: I don't *have* any unstashed local changes and I still got this error.

Comment: I had to leave out "`save --keep-index`".

Comment: I still get an error: **Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting**

Comment: Make it just not overwrite the changes.

Comment: The manual suggests that `save` option is deprecated:
`This option is deprecated in favour of git stash push. It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspecs, and any non-option arguments form the message.`

Comment: Why do you add `save --keep-index`? I went `git stash --help` to try and understand but I am none the wiser, particularly as the stash is due to be dropped immediately afterwards. I'd really like to understand what that's about!

Comment: @mikerodent: I have taken your comment as an opportunity to update the answer. Please check.

Comment: @mikerodent: Thanks for the hint. I missed `push`. Fixed.

Comment: It wasn't a hint, I'm a very low level git person! I just looked at `git stash --help`. From that, it *appears* that the option `--keep-index` belongs with the "sub-command" (if that's what it is) `git stash save`.  But this is beyond my pay grade!

Comment: @MicahWalter did you find a solution, got the same issue.

Comment: @Timo I don't remember one, I'm sorry :(

Comment: It's not a good enough solution. We need a way (or script) to take all these files, and ONLY these files that git warns about, and then for each do "git checkout file" if it is in index, and if not do "rm file" and only then do the git pull. That would be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 469):

This works for me to override all local changes and does not require an identity:

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution if you just want to start over and make your `git pull` work.

Comment: This does not work if a file is not tracked and `git pull` complained about the file since future commits have added a file with same filepath

Answer (score 132):

So many answers here that I hate to add yet another, but all of the above are clunkier than they need to be.  I have to do this all the time as Git seems to become confused and says I have modified files that have not changed (can't revert because they didn't change, but I can't pull because they supposedly have changed)  Simplest and fastest I've found so far is:

```
git stash
git stash drop
git pull
```

**NOTICE**: **local** changes will be lost

Comment: Hm... Dangerous advice. After `stash and drop` you will loose your local changes =(

Comment: @EugenKonkov That's the whole point...  Git sees things as local changes that aren't really changes we want to be kept and we've made no changes that need to be kept.  This way you can quickly toss *all* local changes and then move on!

Comment: @jimsmith Since tossing local changes is the whole point of this, I still struggle with that last part really being necessary at all!

Comment: I am not keeping any local changes so this works perfectly (and efficiently) for me so I can pull.

Comment: This does not work if a file is not tracked and `git pull` complained about the file since future commits have added a file with same filepath

Answer (score 82):

Here is a solution that throws away staged changes:

```
git reset file/to/overwrite
git checkout file/to/overwrite
```

Comment: Annoyingly, if the perceived difference comes from the fact that the file had its newlines changed when it was checked out, this will not fix the problem.

Comment: this is the best answer, imo, because it does not disrupt any staged items, but addresses the problem of the file preventing the pull

Comment: @Timo I do not remember, it was seven years ago.

Answer (score 82):

You can either commit your changes before you do the merge, or you stash them:

1. `git stash save`
2. `git merge origin/master`
3. `git stash pop`

Comment: Point is, you shouldn't have to do this.  Just take the current HEAD material and ..... merge it in!  It's really simple, Git, all other VCS's do it... but nope.  Linus had to make it annoying to use.

Comment: @Jon This solution is for Ubuntu, I have not found anything better then this.

Comment: Unfortunately `--autostash` option is available only with `--rebase` option (

Comment: thats going to introduce so many problems its not worth it. Takes 5 mins at least to load also. Also introduces "Unlink of file" errors. downvote

Comment: Is save option similar to git stash without save? git stash pop means take the last stash from the stack, so apply it to the index.

Answer (score 62):

If you want to discard your local changes on one file you can do the following:

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

Then you could overwrite the file[s] with the latest version just doing:

```
git pull
```

Comment: @pabloasc This is destroy your local changes in that file.

Comment: Yes it does: "What if I want to overwrite them?"

Comment: Original question is not able this, this answer can give someone nightmare who can blindly copy paste the command.

Comment: In case you staged a commit already, you first have to revert the commit via `git reset HEAD~` and then do the `git checkout`

Comment: `git checkout -- <file>` fails with `error: pathspec '<file>' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: And what if I... simply want to merge the changes? I can take care of the fallout and conflicts. But why is it plain refusing?

Answer (score 58):

```
git pull --rebase --autostash
```

> ```
>   -r, --rebase[=false|true|merges|preserve|interactive]
>       When true, rebase the current branch on top of the 
>       upstream branch after fetching. If there is a 
>       remote-tracking branch corresponding to the upstream
> ```

> ```
>   --autostash, --no-autostash
>       Before starting rebase, stash local modifications away if
>       needed, and apply the stash entry when done
> ```

---

I do not know why this is not answered yet, but solution, as you can see is simple. All answers here suggest same: to delete/save your local changes and apply upstream, then (if you `save`) apply your local changes on top.

What `git pull --rebase --autostash` does step-by-step:

```
1. your local changes saved by `--autostash`
2. your local commits saved by `--rebase`
3. commits from upstream applied to your branch
4. your local commits are restored on top of upstream
5. your local changes are restored to working directory
```

My case (probably yours too):

I have local changes (changes at working directory):

[image]

When I try to pull remote changes I get error:

[image]

This changes do not intersect with local changes:

[image]

So when I `pull --rebase --autostash` local changes saved and applied without any problem **automatically**

[image]

Now my local changes are little lower:
[image]

Comment: Nicely done! Can you take out the "TLDR" you have at the top? Perhaps "This is a better answer - PLEASE read."

Comment: @learning2learn: May you please describe why you dislike TLDR?

Comment: Because I think it's worth reading and to me "TL;DR" (too long; didn't read), implies it's too verbose and perhaps not worth reading. But for me of all the different answers on this question, it most closely reflected my issue at the moment, and did exactly what I was looking for. (I'd used stash before, but somehow didn't know of autostash cli option). I think your answer should get more upvotes.

Comment: error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.

Comment: This answer is unique and very important

Comment: So with "your local commits are restored on top of upstream", do you mean they get properly auto-merged with the incoming data? (regardless of conflicts; I can obviously handle those locally)

Comment: @Nyerguds They are rebased. A git commit is essentially a change-log and a pointer to the previous commit(s). Opposed to a merge, where you create a new commit that has both the upstream and your local commit as "parent" and contains info on how to combine both of them, a rebase will rewrite your local commit strings to be based on the upstream's HEAD. So if your local commit encoded some change in line 80, and an upstream commit added 4 lines at the top of the same file, your rebased local commit will now encode the same change but in line 84.

Answer (score 31):

If your repository contains a few files which are removed from `master`:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git fetch origin`
3. `git reset --hard origin/master`
4. `git checkout -b newbranch`

Comment: git reset --hard origin/master is the only thing that worked, out of all these solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried all the answers above but none of them worked. I haven't changed anything and still got this error for file A, and when I tried stash, I got this error with 10 other files. Repeating endlessly... `git reset --hard origin/<branch>` did help!

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me. Thank you!
`git checkout -b newbranch` is out of scope. Question was to pull, so it would be `git pull`.

Answer (score 24):

Sometimes, none of these work.  Annoyingly, due to the LF thing I think, what will work is *deleting* the files, *then* pulling.  Not that I recommend this solution, but if the file doesn't exist, git won't uselessly inform you that your changes (which may not even be changes) will get overridden, and will let you continue.

Use at your own risk.

Comment: When your stuck due to line endings, this method is a life saver

Comment: This isn't working for me.  The files don't exist locally and I am still getting the error.

Comment: this even worked for a git merge master, when none of the other suggestions did

Comment: What happened in me is that, I deleted the file on my local repo, and when I pull, the "about my local changes would be overwritten by merge" came up.

Comment: True for me too.  Tried git checkout HEAD^ and git checkout HEAD -- and git checkout --.  I'm working on my own files and never touched the files with conflicts.  I didn't want to stash and then overwrite everything, just the conflicts...so I ended up deleting the file(s) and repulling.

Comment: For me this worked as the only solution. Git told me I had to commit my ../environment.ts file, however I did not have any changes there and also could not use git stash. I deleted the file and was able to git pull again. I got the exact same environment.ts file from the origin.

Answer (score 22):

Try this

```
git fetch --all 

git reset --hard origin/master

git pull origin master
```

It's work for me to force pull

Comment: We careful, doing so you will lost all local changes!

Answer (score 15):

`git stash save --keep-index` did not worked for me.

below command worked as expected.

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

**It override all local changes if you don't need them.**

Answer (score 12):

In the recent Git, you can add `-r`/`--rebase` on `pull` command to rebase your current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching. The warning should disappear, but there is a risk that you'll get some conflicts which you'll need to solve.

---

Alternatively you can checkout different branch with force, then go back to `master` again, e.g.:

```
git checkout origin/master -f
git checkout master -f
```

Then pull it again as usual:

```
git pull origin master
```

Using this method can save you time from stashing (`git stash`) and potential permission issues, reseting files (`git reset HEAD --hard`), removing files (`git clean -fd`), etc. Also the above it's easier to remember.

Answer (score 11):

This problem is because you have made changes locally to file/s and the same file/s exists with changes in the Git repository, so before pull/push you will need stash local changes:

To overwrite local changes of a single file:

```
git reset file/to/overwrite
git checkout file/to/overwrite
```

To overwrite all the local changes (changes in all files):

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Also this problem may be because of you are on a branch which is not merged with the master branch.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my strategy to solve the problem.

**Problem Statement**

We need to make changes in more than 10 files. We tried `PULL (git pull origin master)`, but Git shouted:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can
>   merge.

We tried to execute `commit` and then `pull`, but they didn't work either.

**Solution**

We were in the *dirty* stage actually, because the files were in the "Staging Area" a.k.a "Index Area" and some were in the "Head Area" a.k.a "local Git directory". And we wanted to pull the changes from the server.

Check this link for information about different stages of Git in a clear manner: *[GIT Stages](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)*

We followed the following steps

- `git stash` (this made our working directory clean. Your changes are stored on the stack by Git).
- `git pull origin master` (Pull the changes from the server)
- `git stash apply` (Applied all the changes from stack)
- `git commit -m 'message'` (Committed the changes)
- `git push origin master` (Pushed the changes to the server)
- `git stash drop` (Drop the stack)

**Let's understand when and why you need stashing**

If you are in the *dirty* state, means you are making changes in your files and then you are compelled, due to any reason, to *pull* or *switch* to another branch for some very urgent work, so at this point you can't pull or switch until you commit your change. The `stash` command is here as a helping hand.

From the book *ProGIT*, 2nd Edition:

> Often, when you’ve been working on part of your project, things are in
>   a messy state and you want to switch branches for a bit to work on
>   something else. The problem is, you don’t want to do a commit of
>   half-done work just so you can get back to this point later. The
>   answer to this issue is the git stash command. Stashing takes the
>   dirty state of your working directory – that is, your modified tracked
>   files and staged changes – and saves it on a stack of unfinished
>   changes that you can reapply at any time.

Comment: Though, git wasn't displaying any local changes. Using just "git stash" helped before merge.

Answer (score 10):

`git reset --hard && git clean -df`

**Caution**: This will reset and delete any untracked files.

Comment: One does not use axe to remove fly from friend's forehead.

Comment: DO NOT use this without the awareness that some files will be DELETED.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me to discard changes on the live remote server and pull from the source control GitHub:

```
git reset --hard
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this for overwrite file

```
git checkout file_to_overwrite
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to solve this problem is:

```
git checkout -- <path/file_name>
```

After that you can overwrite the file by:

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: I had the problem mentioned because I'd updated the index to assume the files were unchanged. It still wouldn't let me do the pull. I used `git checkout -- path/*` just once, and it allowed me to execute the pull after.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep production changes on the server, just merge into a new configuration item. The processing method is as follows:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Maybe you don't execute all operations. You can know what you can do next.

Comment: You can then use the Git diff - w + name of the file to confirm the code merge automatically

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is:

```
git reset --hard && git pull
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to overwrite specific changes, you need some way of telling it which ones you want to forget.

You could try selectively stashing the changes you want to abandon using `git stash --patch` and then dropping that stash with `git stash drop`. You can then pull in the remote changes and merge them as normal.

Answer (score 4):

Error "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge" comes because you have some changes in the local repo that have NOT been commited yet, so before pulling from remote repo just commit the changes in local repo.

Lets say your remote repo has some branch xyz
and you want that remote repo xyz branch to be merged into (copied to) local repo xyz branch then,

```
{
git checkout xyz                  //check out to the respective branch in local repo
git commit -m "commiting message" //commit changes if any, in local repo branch xyz
git pull                          //it pulls remote xyz branch into local xyz branch
}
```

Comment: After you ran git commit command doesn't it ask for git push?

Answer (score 4):

Due to your branch is behind 'origin/dev' by xx commits, and can be fast-forwarded. Try this command:

```
git checkout .
git pullenter code here
```

Hope that fix your issue.

Comment: This sounds most like what the original question is asking for, i.e. the quickest way to just discard the local changes and accept what's at origin. Possibly combined with the other suggestion of `git clean -f` to clear untracked files.

Answer (score 3):

I had a special case of this: I had a file with --assume-unchanged on it. It was hard to locate, as the `git status` command was not showing any changes

Comment: I have this same problem. Did you find a way to get around it? I suppose I could remove and then re-add assume-unchanged... what I did was just checkout those files manually to get unchanged versions... just wondering if there is a way to just make the checkout / rebase / merge just overwrite them.

Comment: No, I had to abandon the whole "assume unchanged " thing.

Answer (score 3):

I was ignoring a file in my repo and when I did `git pull upstream master` I got the following error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
> myfile.js
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
> Aborting

To resolve it I did the following

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged myfile.js
```

I then did `git status` and got this message

> ```
> On branch master
> Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
>         modified:   myfile.js ** 
>         ^^^^ THIS IS KEY ^^^^^ - FILE SHOULD APPEAR MODIFIED!!
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> ```

Then I did `git checkout myfile.js` followed by `git pull upstream master`. This time the git pull operation was successful.

Comment: I recommend dealing with individual files. What I do in this case is first `git diff foobar.js` and then once confirmed nothing precious will be lost: `git restore foobar.js`

Comment: This was the most helpful to me, I had previously "silently ignored" a change with `git update-index --skip-worktree dockerfile`, and was able to restore it with `git update-index --no-skip-worktree dockerfile`

Answer (score 3):

Example

```
[root@localhost www]# git pull
Username for 'http://159.65.151.11': amol
Password for 'http://amol@159.65.151.11':
remote: Counting objects: 34, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 34 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (34/34), done.
From http://159.65.151.11/OpenCC
   f793c8e..b8fe60c  v1.18.0_24Feb2022 -> origin/_v1.18.0_24Feb2022
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        cc/routes/web.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Solution(ignore already commit change in local file)

```
git checkout HEAD^ cc/routes/web.php
git pull
```

Answer (score 2):

If this error is because of line endings,

```
git add
git checkout mybranch
```

will  work. I'm not really sure why it works.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this when pulling from the master.

The way I handled it, using Visual Studio;

1. First, I performed Undo commit on my solution.
2. Then I did the Git pull process.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'm new in git and not sure if my solution is a good idea.

I've tested ALL of answers and none of them worked for me!

But I found another solution:

```
1. Backup both of local and repository versions of the file.
2. Delete the file from repository.
3. git add .
4. git commit
5. git push
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before pulling, you have to commit all files that are not committed yet, then you will not receive that message from AS.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was `delete` the files from outside the IDE that are going to be overwritten, then `pull`.

(you can always backup and manually merge untracked data)

Comment: I do the same. This is the simplest. Execute **rm** to remove the target file or **mv** to backup the target file to a new filename, then execute **git pull**.

Comment: i do the same but it seems wierd to me that this common issue does not have a designated command

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had configured a few months before not to track the file locally with

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <absolute path to file>
```

and that file changed in remote repo and confused git so i used

```
git stash
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <absolute path to file>
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For Pycharm, you can do Git-->Revert and then pull.

Answer (score 0):

This message can also happen if `git-lfs` is used and a file pointer was overwritten by a real file.

then you use:

```
git stash
git lfs migrate import
git pull
```

full output from my case

```
λ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 5d4ad47 Merge branch 'feature/...' into 'master'
Encountered 1 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:
        public/apple-touch-icon.png

λ git pull
Updating 5a4ad44..b25f79d
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        public/apple-touch-icon.png
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting

λ git lfs migrate import
migrate: Fetching remote refs: ..., done
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done
migrate: Rewriting commits: 100% (0/0), done
migrate: Updating refs: ..., done
migrate: checkout: ..., done


λ git pull
Updating 5d4ad47..a25c79a
Fast-forward
 public/apple-touch-icon.png | Bin 2092 -> 130 bytes
 public/favicon.ico          | Bin 6518 -> 1150 bytes
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

see https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2839

Answer (score 0):

Check the file which you are okay to overwrite and lose local changes and then

```
git checkout --ours ${filePath}
git merge upstream/master
```

Answer (score -2):

**For me this worked:-**

1. First I cleaned all the untracked files, run->  `git clean -f`.
2. `git pull`

Comment: For beginners, it should be added that "clean" means removal of files... If you don't want to delete the untracked files, do not do this

Answer (score -3):

Simply commit the local changes and merge
commit -a

Comment: The original question states changes should be overwritten, not committed.  If this is the answer you want you need to include instructions for getting rid of the bogus commit.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to push all files, then try this
`git push --force-with-lease origin master`

Comment: He wants to overwrite his local changes, not the remote.