# Git : Why are my files overwritten by checkout?

Tags: git, checkout, overwrite, git-checkout

I'm new in git.
I got error message `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:` after git checkout.

And I found a good question from Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424142/error-when-changing-to-master-branch-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-c).

But I'm still confused.
Why are my files followed to the branch that I wanted to checkout?
I expected the files are remain in `local` branch and I could simply move to `dev` branch without the files.

---

My situation

```
local branch that I'm focusing(all files are committed)
- add => new_file.java
- delete => deleted_file.java
- modify => modified_file.java

git checkout dev
=> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

---

## Edit

I figured out what happened. Sorry, my explanation above was wrong.

```
admin : is local branch that I'm focusing(all files are committed)
- add => new_file.java
- delete => deleted_file.java
- modify => modified_file.java

someone removed origin/admin branch, and created origin/admin/dev branch.
- my local
ㄴadmin

- origin
ㄴadmin (removed)
ㄴadmin/dev (created)

I tried checkout origin/admin/dev branch!
git checkout origin/admin/dev

- my local
ㄴadmin
ㄴadmin/dev (checkout failed)
```

it may failed. **because my local branch's name 'admin' and remote branch's name 'admin/dev' are crashed.
if branch's name is crashed, checkout is failed and the files are remain my workspace!**
[Using the slash character in Git branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527355/using-the-slash-character-in-git-branch-name)

Sorry for the wrong explanation.

Comment: Maybe you still have uncommited files? Probably your stage is not clean.

Comment: Yes the files remained uncommitted. so I stashed them. thank you for comment

Answer (score 1):

The files will remain in the branch *when you commit them*. Given that they are not committed, well, normally git will move to the branch that you want to checkout *if* the files that are modified on the working tree are *not* changed between your curtent position and where you want to go. Given that is not the case, git is warning you. What can you do? You can either wrap up a new revision by committing those changes, or you can stash them so that you can come back later to the branch and continue what you are doing

```
git stash save -m "will come back later (or whatever you want to say)"
git checkout another-branch
# do lots of things
# when you are ready to go back:
git checkout the-branch-where-i-was
git stash pop
```

And you are back to where you were before.

Comment: thank you! your comment's helpful to me. the problem is just my first explanation was wrong :( I misunderstood the situation.