# Overriden git commit by pull

Tags: git

I committed my changes to my local repo and then did a pull from master which over-rid my changes to be committed. Can I find that commit on my local machine?

Comment: over-rid? Didn't you get a merge conflict?

Comment: Please show us the exact statements you typed. Did you commit or did you not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use git log:

`git log origin/myBranch..myBranch`

That will show all commits on `myBranch` that are not reachable from `origin/myBranch` (Your Remote repository).

Answer (score 0):

You should have received the following error when you attempted to pull if your changes were not committed:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge: file/name/path Please, commit your changes or stash them
>   before you can merge. Aborting

If you didn't receive the error you should have seen a merge conflict as Ishan said above or your changes should still be there.  Check all of your local branches (git  branch  -vv). If you still don't see them, then I would think the changes were never successfully saved.

See this post for additional info: [git pull errorYour local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597104/git-pull-error-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwritten-b)

Comment: No. He *did* commit, he wouldn't get that message. ... or... maybe he didn't. Let's see what the OP updates his question to.