# Git cannot merge DIRTY_WORKTREE and conflict in not edit files

Tags: git, git-merge

I am getting this error when I try to merge master and developer git branch from Zend Studio UI.
When I try to do this by command line I get this error:

```
error: your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge
```

even that the list of files have not been changed. 
After I tried this [How to ignore error on git pull about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/ignoring-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwritten-by-merg)
but on the next try of merge I get conflicting in all files.

How can I solve this mess?

Answer (score 0):

You have modified some files and haven't commit them to your repo. Check your status with

```
git status
```

and add all open changes to your branch. If you have uncommitted changes and you try to merge that error occurs. You can work with `git stash` and `git pop` either.

Comment: But I do not have uncommited changes. With git status I see a list of files in red "Changes not staged for commit".

Comment: running a git checkout the files seems to be reseted but on git status they appear again

Comment: You should really read a git tutorial first ;) https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-add

Comment: I have not change that files, believe me, I do not need a git tutorial, it is been a lot of time I am using git. I have the master branch and the developer branch. I am trying to merge master into developer since I have made some hot fix to master.. I think that the problem could be the fact I have replaced some folders manually (maybe some git system file have corrupted informations)

Comment: Have you enabled your crlf? Then git change all line endings and you have automatically  modified files.

Comment: I fixed the branches by fixing one by one the files. Now I edit a file in master,commit and pushed it, then I switch in developer, trying merge I got a conflict in that file... I am going to delete branches to make a clean branch

Comment: OK by deleting and then re-creating (from developer) the master branch all seems to be fine now. I believe that the problem was Zend Studio command : Replace With-> Branch when replacing the entire project (as I did by replacing master with developer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **DIRTY_WORKTREE** was caused by this sequence:

1. In a commit, I committed also some files that I should have ignored
2. In the next commit I *modified the .gitignore* that ignore the above files
3. Try to *rebase on top of another branch where my change to .gitignore is missing*

In this scenario, Eclipse thinks your working tree is dirty. Indeed, it is not obvious *comparing two filesets when one of the two is ignoring some files and the other is not*.

To **solve the issue** in Eclipse (works for any Eclipse based IDE like Zend Studio) I did the following:

- Modify the .gitignore so it is the same as the one in the branch I want to rebase on
- Happily start the rebasing or rebasing with merge.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had **uncommitted** changes.

I committed my changes and then I was able to **merge** successfully.