# git fetch don't load latest version of the project

Tags: git

I have my project on two computers and I want to download all changes from **computer 1** to **computer 2**. I use `git fetch --all` for it, but it don't load all the changes. I make commit every day on **computer 1** and on **computer 2** github says, that the last commit was made 5 days ago. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1**

[image]

Comment: Did you push to github from that other computer?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I did

Comment: @dima, can you post the output of `git status` and `git remote -v`?

Comment: @KaranChadha added to Edit 1

Comment: remote name is origin, but you used remote while git push,instead use git push <remote name> <branch name>

Comment: @dima - a typo from my side. please excuse. correct statement is `git push origin master`

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi with `git push origin master` it says that everything is up to date

Comment: @dima offcurse from computer1 once you push code to live it will say everything is upto date. And on computer2 you just need to pull them down.Let me know what you want?

Comment: I've deleted my local changes like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-to-ignore-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-m and made git pull. Thanks everyone

Comment: @dima Then all looks good :) . use `git remote add origin <URL including .git>` and `git pull origin` from **Computer 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to push the code to upstream(github/bitbucket repo) from computer1, it will available there.

we use `git push <remote name> <branch name>`

You already have **remote name : origin** so use it

From upstream you need to get that data.

So normal we clone it first, or get add a remote to pull the code.

In your case, instead of `git fetch` you need `git pull upstream master`,so that the code will be fetch and merged too.

And it shows you don't have proper access to the repo to push as you misplace remote at git push. Even remote is consider as a name here. so use your remote name which is display on **git remote -v**

Remote has a name ,so use **git push origin master** to push the code

Answer (score 1):

`git status`, `git remote -v` **AND** `git push origin master`
Do these from the computer which has your committed changes