# IntelliJ: Lost files after "Update project" and can't find them on Local history

Tags: node.js, git, intellij-idea

I have a nodejs project and i use IntelliJ to run it. Lately the project structure is not appearing as it used to, as if the project was not compiling. So, while searching for answers, I clicked on the "Update project" button on the right top, but quickly realised it was going to update based on what was on the remote repo.
I've been developing for a few weeks without a single commit because my company asked me to (don't ask why), and the code had sensible data so I didn't have a backup.

After clicking that button, IntelliJ asked me if I wanted to merge my project files with the remote ones, I just pressed Cancel, and that was enough for IntelliJ to merge my entire project and lose a bunch of files I've been working with.

Suprisingly, they're not even on the Local History list. Even though it says "[279 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czH5R.jpg)" there I can't click or find any of the files.

Despite not being able to find them, I went to the changes.storageData file under IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\LocalHistory, searched for the names of the files I'm looking for, and found them all there, which makes me think there's still a way of finding them.

So, does anyone know where I can find deleted files after pressing the git "Update project" button on IntelliJ when they're not on the Local History file list?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you using Local History at root level? Can you post a screenshot? In any case, IntelliJ should not remove local files like that unless you specifically ask it to...

Comment: That's exactly what I though. I couldn't add a screenshot because I don't have enough "points" here I guess, but yeah, I was using it at root level.

Comment: Do you remember the package names you was working with? Note that you can use Local history for packages/folders, which should show all tracked modifications in that directory/package.

Comment: It just happened to meet too

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the files were not committed, so Update could not delete them, because git merge/rebase do not start when there are uncommitted changes (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-to-ignore-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-m) question)

They were probably automatically stashed before the update, and not unstashed because the update was actually canceled.

So the first place to check is git stash `VCS - Git - Unstash...` or Shelf (if Update project is configured to use Shelf)

Comment: I did git stach and I got 74 files changed, 1432 insertions(+), 5988 deletions(-), but I still haven't got any changes on the directories I wanted nor my files back.