# Unable to install package

Tags: go, ethereum

Initially posted this on the Ethereum forum but feel that there might be more knowledge of the issue here as it is a Golang/git package installation issue

---

I am trying to compile smart contracts using the go-ethereum client.

I have go installed on my pc and installed ran the following commands:

```
go get -u github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum 
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ 
make
```

Which all work fine.

When I run

```
make devtools
```

I get the following error:

```
Pros-MacBook-Pro:go-ethereum Santi$ make devtools
env GOBIN= go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer
# cd /Users/pro/go/src/golang.org/x/tools; git pull --ff-only
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        CONTRIBUTING.md
        blog/blog.go
        cmd/godoc/autocert.go
        cmd/godoc/blog.go
        cmd/godoc/godoc_test.go
        cmd/godoc/handlers.go
        cmd/godoc/main.go
        cmd/godoc/x.go
        cmd/goimports/goimports.go
        cmd/gomvpkg/main.go
        cmd/goyacc/yacc.go
        cmd/guru/guru.go
        cmd/guru/guru_test.go
        cmd/guru/main.go
        cmd/guru/referrers.go
        cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers/int_test.go
        cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers/main.go
        cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers/main.golden
        cmd/present/static/styles.css
        cmd/present/templates/slides.tmpl
        cmd/stringer/endtoend_test.go
        cmd/stringer/stringer.go
        cmd/tip/tip.go
        go/ast/astutil/imports.go
        go/ast/astutil/imports_test.go
        go/buildutil/allpackages_test.go
        go/buildutil/fakecontext.go
        go/buildutil/util_test.go
        go/gcexportdata/example_test.go
        go/gcexportdata/gcexportdata.go
        go/gcexportdata/main.go
        go/gcimporter15/bexport.go
        go/gcimporter15/bexport19_test.go
        go/gcimporter15/bexport_test.go
        go/gcimporter15/bimport.go
        go/gcimporter15/exportdata.go
        go/gcimporter15/gcimporter.go
        go/gcimporter15/gcimporter_test.go
        go/gcimporter15/isAlias18.go
        go/gcimporter15/isAlias19.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/a.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/b.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/exports.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/issue15920.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/issue20046.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/p.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/versions/test.go
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/versions/test_go1.7_0.a
        go/gcimporter15/testdata/versions/test_go1.7_1.a
        go/internal/gccgoimporter/gccgoinstallation_test.go
        go/internal/gccgoimporter/importer_test.go
        go/internal/gccgoimporter/parser.go
        go/loader/loader_test.go
        go/ssa/interp/external.go
        go/ssa/ssa.go
        go/vcs/vcs.go
        go/vcs/vcs_test.go
        godoc/cmdline.go
        godoc/cmdline_test.go
        godoc/dirtrees.go
        godoc/dl/dl.go
        godoc/godoc.go
        godoc/index.go
        godoc/pres.go
        godoc/server.go
        godoc/spec.go
        godoc/static/gen.go
        godoc/static/godoc.html
        godoc/static/godocs.js
        godoc/static/makestatic.go
        godoc/static/package.html
        godoc/static/playground.js
        godoc/static/static.go
        godoc/static/style.css
        godoc/template.go
        godoc/vfs/emptyvfs.go
        godoc/vfs/gatefs/gatefs.go
        godoc/vfs/mapfs/mapfs.go
        godoc/vfs/namespace.go
        godoc/vfs/os.go
        godoc/vfs/vfs.go
        godoc/vfs/zipfs/zipfs.go
        imports/fastwalk.go
        imports/fastwalk_dirent_fileno.go
        imports/fastwalk_dirent_ino.go
        imports/fastwalk_portable.go
        imports/fastwalk_test.go
        imports/fastwalk_unix.go
        imports/fix.go
        imports/fix_test.go
        imports/imports.go
        imports/sortimports.go
        present/parse.go
        refactor/eg/eg.go
        refactor/eg/eg_test.go
        refactor/eg/rewrite.go
        refactor/eg/testdata/no_after_return.template
        refactor/rename/rename.go
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 73e16cff..d74aaa1f
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer: exit status 1
make: *** [devtools] Error 1
```

Hoping that this wasnt too serious, I tries creating my go file with the following line:

```
abigen -abi=Store.abi --pkg=store --out=Store.go
bash: abigen: command not found
```

I suspect this has to do with my failed install and will appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: This is a `git` issue. The command printing the error is `git pull --ff-only`. Fix or remove that checkout.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not sure how to fix the check out. Should I report it as a bug or would you be able to give some guidance ?

Comment: If you don't know how to use git, just delete the directory and `go get` will fetch it again.

Comment: Did you do something inappropriate such as make your entire GOPATH a single git repository?

Comment: @MichaelHampton newbie here can you please expand on this?

Comment: @JimB deleted it , but its still not working

Comment: @MichaelHampton the git file are in the github.com folder in the $GOPATH dont think I have messed with these

Comment: @Data_Kid: you should not have any git files in `$GOPATH/src/github.com`. I don't know how you got to this state, but you might need to just wipe the GOPATH and start over.

Comment: Apologies they arent there but in the package ie. $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

- `cd /Users/pro/go/src/golang.org/x/tools` (This is the repo that had the issues)
- Run `git stash save && git merge origin/master && git stash pop`
- Run `make devtools` (The make file contains the instructions for installing abigen and placing it in `usr/bin`

I got help from this answer:

[How do I ignore an error on 'git pull' about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-do-i-ignore-an-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritt)

Comment: You should not have changes in that directory at all. If you're using the upstream package, then your checkout should match that source. Keeping the modifications is only delaying problems for later.