# git repquest aborts with "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-push, ubuntu-server

i have a codeigniter project in ubuntu server

i normally upload files to bitbucket. and in ubuntu server i pull the files from bit bucket

but in project, users uploads images in frontend of the website.

And when i pull, git says local contain changes that are not in remote and aborting the pull

so i typed

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git pull
```

is this the right way to do this?

Do i need to exclude the uploads folder from git..

folder structure

```
var/ww/html

application
uploads
.git
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ignore an error on 'git pull' about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-do-i-ignore-an-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritt)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Your+local+changes+to+the+following+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge

Answer (score 0):

Typically user uploads should not be considered part of your code repository. You can tell git to ignore that folder by opening `.gitignore` and adding the line `uploads/*`

The error you are getting is indicating, however, that your local branch has updates that your remote does not (meaning it is ahead). Assuming no other developers (or users) are editing your remote branch, you can get by this by calling `git pull` before you make your changes, and then add, commit and push your changes to the remote.

If you have already made changes and then your remote changes, you can get around this by calling `git stash` to store your changes elsewhere and then `git stash apply` to bring them back after you have pulled the changes to the remote branch.

If you are working on a project with other developers, you may want to read up on proper team git workflows, particularly how to use feature branches and pull requests.