# Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git

Similar questions have been asked here, but I believe this particular one hasn't.

I have a file `params.dat` that stores some parameter values for my code.

This file is constantly changing, since I change the parameter values often, so I added a  static version of it into my repo at home along with the rest of the code, and then ignored it with:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged params.dat
```

Everything works fine, except when I have to make some change to the static version of the file (which happens no so often). What I do is, first un-ignore it with:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged params.dat
```

then make the necessary changes, commit and push them to Github and finally ignore the file again.

This works flawlessly with my main repo, but when I try to `git pull` from the repo I keep at work, I get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    params.dat
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I tried, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/1391441), to do:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

but I get:

```
error: Entry 'params.dat' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
```

I also tried:

```
git stash
git merge origin/master
git stash pop
```

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588386/1391441), but after `git stash` I get:

```
No hay cambios locales que guardar
```

(roughly translates to "No local changes to save")

To make things clear: I am not interested in keeping *any* changes on the `params.dat` file on the repo I keep at my work. I just want it to be an exact copy of whatever I pushed last to Github from home.

What is the appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"No local changes to save" in this case means `git stash` doesn't see local changes in `params.dat` as it is assumed to be unchanged.

Before pulling, you have to make local changes visible, and get rid of them in `params.dat` file if any:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged params.dat
$ git checkout -- params.dat
$ git pull
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged params.dat
```

If there are not-commited local changes in other files you are interested in, use stashing to keep them and restore after pulling:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged params.dat
$ git checkout -- params.dat
$ git stash
$ git pull
$ git stash pop
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged params.dat
```

Comment: Won't this keep the changes to `params.dat`? The OP said he didn't want to "keep *any* changes on `params.dat`".

Comment: @wspurgin hmm... I see `git stash pop` in the question, so added it... Let me re-read it)

Comment: maybe `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged params.dat` then `git checkout params.data`? Then pulling and updating the index?

Comment: @wspurgin exactly! Thanks for pointing this out... I've missed that he is not interested in local changes... so no need in stashing there.

Comment: glad I could help. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you @Stas, as soon as I can I'll try it at work and mark it as accepted if it works, or comment here if it doesn't.

Comment: Just tried it, your answer worked perfectly. Thank you @Stas!

Comment: @Gabriel You're welcome! Also, it may be convenient in your case to use `git pull --rebase` instead of `git pull` if you have new local (not pushed yet) commits. It will rebase them on top of commits pulled from upstream, instead of creating a merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the aforementioned steps, but it didn't work for me.

After hours online, I found out somewhere that you can just `rename that file` then do your `pull` or `reset` or `rebase`.

This will pull the remote file for you (recreate the renamed file).

Now you can delete the `renamed file` and life goes on.